Recovering parentless Qt objects from specific memory region
My code injects itself into closed-source Qt5 application. During startup app creates some global objects which I'd like to access. Code is injected in the main loop, it is not present at the moment of object creation.
Sample code:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QObject objectOfInterest();  <-- need this

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    return app.exec();  <-- injection happens somewhere here
}

These objects are always created in same region of memory between QApplication and QQmlApplicationEngine (Gammaray screenshot).

Offsets between entries and order are not consistent, but memory location is always the same. They have no parent (QObject(0x0)), so there is no easy way to access them. GammaRay gets this information by hooking object creation using LD_PRELOAD which is not desirable.
Here is my idea: iterate through memory between qApp and QQmlApplicationEngine in 4-byte intervals and check if this address is a valid QObject:
auto b = qmlEngine(someQmlEntity);
auto qAppEngine = (char *) qobject_cast<QQmlApplicationEngine *>(b);
char *p = (char *) qApp;
while (p < qAppEngine) {
    QObject *obj;
    obj = (QObject *) (void *) p;
    printf("class name %s\n", obj->metaObject()->className());
    p = p + 4;
}

This code fails after first iteration, because (char*)qApp + 4 is not a valid QObject. Wrapping obj->metaObject() into try-catch block also crashes the application.
Is there a way to recover these objects in a nice way? Am I doing casts wrong?

There is an undocumented API designed to allow hooking into object creation. Use it like this:
#include <QtCore/private/qhooks_p.h>

void addCallback(QObject* obj)
{
    std::printf("Created object at %p\n", obj);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    qtHookData[QHooks::AddQObject] = reinterpret_cast<quintptr>(&addCallback);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ...
}

Note that there is no thread-safe way to remove or change the callback. In practice it may work, however, a safer option is to change the callback into a no-op with something like a global std::atomic<bool> once you are done and just live with the minor performance impact.
If you use CMake, link like this to make the private headers for the hook visible:
target_link_libraries(your_app Qt::CorePrivate ...)


Nice, but there are two issues. First, my code is being injected after creation of these objects (should've made this clearer in question). Second, there is no mention of hooks in my qt distribution (5.3.2).

@user1938027 What do you mean by "there is no mention of hooks"?

@musicamante $ grep -ril qhook ->
qtbase/src/3rdparty/freetype/src/tools/glnames.py. That's it, no hooks included in this distribution.

@user1938027 Well, for starters, Qt 5.3.2 was released more than ten years ago. If you have a restraint for such an old version, you should mention it in your post to begin with. Interestingly enough, the review linked above seems to have been only applied since 5.6 (or 5.4?) at least.

It is possible to find all QObjects by following pointers to staticMetaObject method. This is the only static method of QObject.
Decompile your binary and find initialization of your object. In my case it was something like this (Ghidra):
void MyClass(void **param_1)

{
  void *pvVar1;
  void *local_28;
  
  local_28 = __stack_chk_guard;
  QTConnectionMagic(param_1);
  *param_1 = &PTR_FUN_MyClass;
  operator.new(0x10);
  pvVar1 = (void *)RequestDefaultQObjectMyClass();  <----
  ...


void RequestDefaultQObjectMyClass(QObject *param_1)

{
  int iVar1;
  void *pvVar2;
  
  iVar1 = __stack_chk_guard;
  QObject::QObject(param_1,(QObject *)0x0);
  param_1->field0_0x0 = &PTR_FUN_QObject_vtable;  <----

Here is vtable with staticMetaObject address:

                            PTR_FUN_QObject_vtable                          XREF[2]:     RequestDefaultQObjectMyClass:00000(*), 
1       007bca14 69 ac 75 00     addr       FUN_0076ac68+1
2       007bca18 c5 ac 75 00     addr       LAB_0076acc4+1
3       007bca1c 39 ad 75 00     addr       FUN_0076ad38+1
4       007bca20 39 f2 45 00     addr       FUN_0092f238+1
5       007bca24 29 f3 45 00     addr       FUN_0092f328+1
6       007bca28 60 78 03 00     addr       <EXTERNAL>::QObject::event
7       007bca2c 6c 78 03 00     addr       <EXTERNAL>::QObject::eventFilter
8       007bca30 78 78 03 00     addr       <EXTERNAL>::QObject::timerEvent
9       007bca34 84 78 03 00     addr       <EXTERNAL>::QObject::childEvent
10      007bca38 90 78 03 00     addr       <EXTERNAL>::QObject::customEvent
11      007bca3c 9c 78 03 00     addr       <EXTERNAL>::QObject::connectNotify
12      007bca40 a8 78 03 00     addr       <EXTERNAL>::QObject::disconnectNotify
                             PTR_staticMetaObject_007bca44           
                                                                     
13      007bca44 94 82 03 00     addr       QObject::staticMetaObject  <-----

Your class must reference PTR_FUN_QObject_vtable, so vtable's address must be somewhere nearby its' address.
auto staticMetaObj = (char *) (&QObject::staticMetaObject); // 0xb5814fa0

Our object is at 0xb796642, pointer to vtable reference must be at 0xb796642 + 4 (param_1->field0_0x0) (32-bit application).
It's value is 0xb7966540. At 0xb7966540 is vtable address = 0xb5814f4c.
There is a mismatch between expected vtable address and real one.
Expected: staticMetaObj - 13*4, actual: 0xb5814fa0 - 21*4 = 0xb5814f4c.
There are 8 more pointers which came from... some other class? Qt sources are not making that clear.
At this point we can follow pointer chain to get objects.
Search memory from qApp to QQmlApplicationEngine looking for vtable address 0xb5814f4c, find some:
auto b = qmlEngine(someQmlObject);
auto end = (char *) qobject_cast<QQmlApplicationEngine *>(b);

auto metatable = (char *) (&QObject::staticMetaObject) - 21 * 4;
char *curpos = (char *) qApp;
std::vector<char *> pointersToMetatable{};
while (curpos < end) {
    curpos = curpos + 4;
    auto pointer = (void *) curpos;
    if (*(void **) pointer == (void *) metatable) {
        pointersToMetatable.emplace_back(curpos);
    }
}

for (auto pointer: pointersToMetatable) {
    curpos = (char *) qApp;
    while (curpos < end) {
        curpos = curpos + 4;
        auto curPointer = (void *) curpos;
        if (*(void **) curPointer == pointer) {
            printf("found %p\n", curpos - 4);
            auto obj = (QObject *) (curpos - 4);
            printf("%s\n", obj->metaObject()->className());
            break;
        }
    }
}


found 0xb7982608
MyClass
found 0xb7926528
QEglFSIntegrationPlugin
found 0xb793fadc
QPlatformNativeInterface
found 0xb79481c0
QObject
found 0xb7948268
QEGLPlatformCursorUpdater
...


It breaks at Gammaray classes, so make sure to disable it beforehand.
This is an inaccurate answer (vtable address mismatch), but hey, it works.
EDIT:
This is not 100%-proof and may crash from time no matter what you do. In my case memory area with objects is huge and it seems that objects don't clear memory after being deleted. Therefore it is possible to find references to dead objects; calling ->metaObject() on them results in segfault. There are no obvious differences between alive object and dead one.
